# image itself will not change but size of it will(absolute beginner)

Tags: html, css

just like title says. I have tried multiple image formats as well as every thing online abut changing image size(all of the ones that change dynamically did not change anything at all when set to 20%)

[this is it at 12px by 12px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88187.png)

[this is it normally at what I made the image at before editing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCFlz.png)

I know it actually changing with the `px` thing because of how the code I borrowed highlights the background of the thing the mouse is over and that changes hen the `px` is changed. and it think only shows the images top when `px` because the bar as a whole has `overflow: hidden;` in its properties thing
and this is the code. also when not told to be 12px none of the text is visible and cannot be scrolled to.

```
css:
.color-stem {
  float: left;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}

  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;

html: <a href="index.HTML", class="color-stem"><img src="website logo.png"></a>
```

Comment: I started to make a snippet of your code but BOTH your HTML and CSS are malformed

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. There is way too much vague stuff in your question. Don't just _talk_ about how stuff happens when something gets hovered, and how there is overflow: hidden on something ... _show_ a proper example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the 'img' tag selector in your css, to target the image inside your anchor element.

Css:
.color-stem img{..;}

Or move your class inside the image element in your html.

<img class"your class name"/>

And use your class name to target the image,as you were doing in your code.